# is vptr name mangled in c++?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Even though there are so many articles on how virtual functions are handled in c++, i could not clear one basic doubt. Is vptr variable of derived class overrided by base class variable. Is the ptr varible also name mangled?

```
Class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test();
};

class Derived 
{
public:
     virtual void test();
};
```

If I call

```
Base b = new Derived();
b->test();
```

It transforms to

```
(*b->vptr[<index>])(b);
```

Where index points to vtable entry.

My doubt is whether is this vptr also name mangled ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't even acknowledge the existence of a `vptr` in polymorphic classes because it's an implementation detail and therefore it isn't even a requirement that compilers implement virtual functions in this way. So no, `vptr` is not a reserved keyword (which is what I think you're trying to ask).

Comment: I have this doubt because, if base class object pointer which is initialized to derived class( In my case b), calls virtual function, which vptr it will use, is it base class vptr or child class vptr ?

Comment: It is the base class vptr (which exists in all derived classes too) that points to the virtual table of the derived class. Of course all this is implementation dependent so you can't access it from your C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access vptr in C++ by language means so answer in "no" - no such variable and name and thus no its mangling :)